# setSectionBox method of Section tool displaying model edges

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Always when I make a SectionBox with `sectionExtension.setSectionBox(box3)` or default restore state of PushPin extension, onto an issue which has section box, viewer displays model edges, is there a way to set it off?

**EDIT:** just found `setDisplayEdges` method, it removes all edges, is there a way to set it off only on elements off cutplane?

[image: model bounds]